# Using context.query in Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, deployment, frontend, react-context, next.js13

Looks like my context.query that i was using in Nextjs 12 is not working on 13. What should i use instead of context.query? Context API? useSearchParams? Im still a noob developer and im pretty lost.

This was the code i was using in Next js 12(the getServerSideProps its already gonne in new next13 project) :

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  let curso: any;
  let { id, type }: any = context.query;

  curso = await treatCursoData(curso, id, type);

  if (!curso) return { notFound: true };

  return { props: { curso, type: type || null } };
};
```

I only tried useSearchParams but couldn't make it work.

Thank you a lot for any help:)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I needed to use searchParams.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).